# tornadofx listview is creating one additional null listcellfragment than items in the list

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I have a ViewModel for a ListView with 3 players in it:

```
object PlayerListViewModel : ViewModel() {
    lateinit var players : ObservableList<Player>

    init{

    }

    fun loadPlayers(){
        players = Engine.selectedGame.players.asObservable()
    }
}

class PlayerListView : View() {
    private val vm = PlayerListViewModel

    override val root = VBox()

    init {
        vm.loadPlayers()

        root.replaceChildren {
            style {
                spacing = 25.px
                alignment = Pos.CENTER
                padding = box(0.px, 15.px)
            }

            listview(vm.players){
                style{
                    background = Background.EMPTY
                    prefWidth = 300.px
                }
                isFocusTraversable = false
                isMouseTransparent = true
                cellFragment(PlayerCardFragment::class)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the `listview` is creating 4 `PlayerCardFragments`, with the first having a null `item` property and the last 3 having the correct `Player` item reference. This is the `PlayerCardFragment` definition:

```
class PlayerCardFragment : ListCellFragment<Player>() {
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger { }

    private val vm = PlayerViewModel().bindTo(this)
    private lateinit var nameLabel : Label
    private lateinit var scoreLabel : Label

    override val root = hbox {
        addClass(UIAppStyle.playerCard)
        nameLabel = label(vm.name) { addClass(UIAppStyle.nameLabel) }
        scoreLabel = label(vm.score) { addClass(UIAppStyle.scoreLabel) }
    }

    init {
        logger.debug { "Initializing fragment for ${this.item} and ${vm.name.value}" }
        EventBus.channel(EngineEvent.PlayerChanged::class)
            .observeOnFx()
            .subscribe() {
                vm.rollback() //force viewmodel (PlayerViewModel) refresh since model (Player) does not implement observable properties
                logger.debug { "${vm.name.value}'s turn is ${vm.myTurn.value}" }
                root.toggleClass(UIAppStyle.selected, vm.myTurn)
     }
}
```

When running the application, the `PlayerCardFragment` initializations print out "Initializing fragment for null and null" four times, but the list appears perfectly correctly with the 3 Player items. Later during execution, wnen there is an `Engine.PlayerChanged` event received, the Oberver function prints:
"null's turn is false"
"Adam's turn is false"
"Chad's turn is true"
"Kyle's turn is false"
These are the correct players, with the correct turn statuses. The `listview` appears perfectly well with the styling changes. I'm just not sure where that first null ListCellFragment is coming from.

Comment: I don't speak kotlin, but this looks like the equivalent of a JavaFX `ListCell` implementation. If so, typically cells will be created initially empty, and then "reused" when the data are added to the list view, adding items to the empty cells. Typically more cells will be initially created than there are items, so the list view can easily handle scrolling, etc. None of the output here is particularly surprising to me; if the list view is displaying correctly, why do you care?

Comment: I believe it is equivalent. I didn't realize that list views would create more fragments than needed and reuse them so thanks for that. Only reason I care is because these null fragments are registering subscriptions on the EventBus and executing their observer routines for published events. If I didn't know where 1 null fragment was coming from, I don't know where more might come from and would would be a memory leak concern for me. It's still a bit strange to me that if the list view is creating more than needed that the first one in the list would be null and not the last.

Comment: Which cells the `ListView` uses for which items is an implementation detail, and won't necessarily be consistent throughout the lifespan of the `ListView` (`updateItem()` will be invoked when a cell previously used for one item is reused for another). Also note that if the `ListView` is larger than needed for the number of items, it will fill with `ListCell`s, some of which will be empty, which is why it might create more cells than it has items.

Comment: I can move my subscription to an override of updateItem. Is there a corresponding method to override for cleanup? Similar in nature to this question that got no answer: https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/issues/906

Comment: There isn’t (at least, not in JavaFX), but there’s no real need for one. The number of cells will only grow if the `ListView` grows in (layout) size, and is bounded basically by the size of the scene. Once the `ListView` is out of scope, the cells should be out of scope too.  Basically, cells are constructed very rarely, `updateItem()` may be called frequently (eg during scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to give `ItemViewModel` functionality to a view model by having everything around it change. Why not change the `PlayerViewModel` to have the functionality instead? Easiest way to imagine is to create bindings out of generic properties, then have them all changed and committed with by listening to the `itemProperty`:

```
class Player(var foo: String?, var bar: Int?)

class PlayerViewModel() : ItemViewModel<Player>() {
    val foo = bind { SimpleStringProperty() }
    val bar = bind { SimpleIntegerProperty() }
    
    init {
        itemProperty.onChange { 
            foo.value = it?.foo
            bar.value = it?.bar
        }
    }

    override fun onCommit() {
        item?.let { player ->
            player.foo = foo.value
            player.bar = bar.value?.toInt()
        }
    }
}
```

Is  it pretty? No. Does it keep you from having to implement an event system? Yes.